# "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket" while creating listen socket in c#

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have written a server program and sometimes get following exception.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation was attempted on something that is   not a socket
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType  socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener..ctor(IPAddress localaddr, Int32 port)
```

This exception is observed in very rare occasions

The code snippet is as follows::

```
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
                        listener .Start(100);
```

Can any body help me to find root cause of this. I have searched on many forums and have not been able to reach definite conclusion why it is happening.

Comment: I would like to recommend you to use the network tracing (see [Enabling Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6sbz1dx)).

Comment: @Serge This is happening in client computer that too unproductively. Also we are using .Net 2.0 while the tool suggested by you seems to be related with .Net 4.0. This exception occurs when service is trying to restart after service was crashed